# Php Date Conversion and date difference

Tags: php, datetime

I have two dates like 
2016-01-25 07:33:54 and current date 30-01-2016 01.27.00

I want to get difference between these dates with dates in number of hours, number of minutes and number of seconds .

Comment: difference in hh:mm:ss, or the diff in hh, the diff in mm AND  the diff in ss???

Comment: I want to have a difference in number of Days , like if you can see there is 10 days of difference , now same way with the time , like how many diff of hours there is, same like minus and seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this.

checkout my code below.

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2014-02-16 04:04:26 AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-02-11 05:36:56 AM');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


echo $interval->format('%R%a days')." days ".$interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes".$interval->format('%s')." Seconds";

?>
```

Comment: try searching all the formats given by new DateTime function in php. You will get better idea .

Answer (score 2):

```
$fromDate   = "2016-01-25 07:33:54";
$toDate     = "30-01-2016 01.27.00";
$difference = strtotime($toDate)-strtotime($fromDate);
echo "Seconds : ".$difference."<br>";
echo "Minutes : ".($difference/60)."<br>";
echo "Hours : ".($difference/(60*60));
```

Or

A Easy way

```
$fromDate   = "2016-01-25 07:33:54";
$toDate     = "30-01-2016 01.27.00";
$datetime1 = new DateTime($toDate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($fromDate);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$days = $interval->d;
$hours = $interval->h;
$minutes = $interval->i;
$seconds = $interval->s;
echo "$days days, $hours Hrs, $minutes Mins, $seconds Sec";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
use strtotime to find time difference between two dates.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php